# Setting request header in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, http-headers

I have trouble with a piece of ajax code. This is the error message I get from mod security:

> /ajaxController.php?mod=catalog&op=ajaxSeenProducts HTTP/1.1
>
> Access denied with code 400 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at
>   REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"]
>   [line "12"] [id "960012"] [msg "POST request must have a
>   Content-Length header"] [severity "WARNING"] [tag
>   "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/EVASION"]

There is a module in the web shop I am working on, which shows the last viewed products, and the jquery code I have is this:

```
$('#seen_products_box').ready(function() {
   $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",
      url: "{HOME}ajaxController.php?mod=catalog&op=ajaxSeenProducts",
      success: function(seenProducts) {
          $('#seen_products_box').empty();
          $('#seen_products_box').append(seenProducts);
      }
   });
});
```

While searching for the solution, I have found in various places that I need to set the

> Content-length

parameter, but all I have found is in this format:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
```

Is there any way to set the request header in the code format I have provided above? I have already tried something like:

headers: { 
        "Content-Length": params.length
    }

but with no result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use code like:

```
                var url = '{HOME}ajaxController.php?';
                var data = "mod=catalog&op=ajaxSeenProducts";
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "html",
                    type:'post',
                    success:function(seenProducts){
                        $('#seen_products_box').empty();
                        $('#seen_products_box').append(seenProducts);
                    },
                    error:function(response){

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `beforeSend` function to set the `headers`

```
$('#seen_products_box').ready(function() {
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",
beforeSend: function (request)
{
            request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
},
  url: "{HOME}ajaxController.php?mod=catalog&op=ajaxSeenProducts",
  success: function(seenProducts) {
      $('#seen_products_box').empty();
      $('#seen_products_box').append(seenProducts);
   }
 });
});
```

or other way you can do it like

```
$('#seen_products_box').ready(function() {
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",
 headers: {"X-Test-Header": "test-value"},
  url: "{HOME}ajaxController.php?mod=catalog&op=ajaxSeenProducts",
  success: function(seenProducts) {
      $('#seen_products_box').empty();
      $('#seen_products_box').append(seenProducts);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said above, I have already tried using "headers: { "Content-Length": "params.length" }"  and that didn't work. And without that, the code works but I get the error. I am running out of ideas...

Comment: I have tried beforeSend as well, and that didn't work either - without it the code works but mode security shows the error, with it the code  doesn't work